# ActiveAdmin Issues on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activeadmin

On heroku when I enter

```
https://harmony-payment.herokuapp.com/admin/login
```

And after login it redirect to that page

```
https://harmony-payment.herokuapp.com/admin/users/1
```

In both these cases it gives an error

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

It works when I enter only

```
/admin
```

On localhost everthing works correctly